# ARM Template : Unable to access Array of object as a parameter to the resource Template

Tags: arrays, json, azure, azure-rm-template

I am trying to create an ARM template to deploy multiple instance of multiple resources. I need to create below list of resource:

1. 10 Cloud Services
2. 2 Keyvaults
3. 30 Storage Accounts
4. 30 Eventhub Namespaces

all the above resources has to be created under single resource group, but because of the resource naming convention policy the resource names have to be passed through the ParameterTemplate.json, and can't be auto generated.

Below are the snippets of parameter and template files to create multiple storage accounts.

But somehow i am not able to access the parameter values in the resource section of the template.

**Parameter.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "StorageAccount": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "test01",                    
                    "skuName": "Standard_LRS",                    
                    "kind" : "Storage"
                },
                {
                    "name": "test02",                    
                    "skuName": "Standard_LRS",                    
                    "kind" : "Storage"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Template.json**

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "StorageAccount": {
            "type": "array",
            "defaultValue": []
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "apiVersion": "2017-06-01",
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",                        
            "name": "[parameters('StorageAccount')[copyIndex()].name]",         
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
            "sku": {
                "name": "Standard_LRS"
            },
            "copy": { 
              "name": "StorageAccount",               
              "count": "[length(parameters('StorageAccount'))]",
            }, 
            "kind": "Storage",
            "properties": {}
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {}
}
```

please suggest me any improvements in the template, or other approach to achieve the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tested your template and it work perfectly fine (and it looks fine). Tested with:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName name -TemplateParameterFile params.json -TemplateFile template.json
```

ps. you forgot to pass in sku and kind into the template

```
"sku": {
    "name": "[parameters('StorageAccount')[copyIndex()].skuName]"
},
"kind": "[parameters('StorageAccount')[copyIndex()].kind]"
```

Comment: the sku & kind were hard coded in the template, but i used your suggestion and still getting the below error. 

Code    : InvalidTemplateDeployment
Message : The template deployment 'd24c43c2-2167-441d-9b82-e928cf79fd27' is not valid according to the validation
          procedure. The tracking id is 'e97b715d-6a37-4ddf-8985-c44247c2d522'. See inner errors for details. Please
          see https://aka.ms/arm-deploy for usage details.
Details : {Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Cmdlets.SdkModels.PSResourceManagerError}

Comment: well, check the real error (using -debug) because i literally pasted your template and it worked

Comment: the resource name were already created, so the template was throwing internal error, got the resource name error when executed the command with -Debug,.. Thanks @4c74356b41